# How to combine two data table and merge in to new datatables

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq, datatable

I have a code that will read all the excel file in a workbook and will save in to a datatables in a dataset. Now based on certain condition i have to merge datatables in to new one and store in to a oracle database.  following code i used to merge two datatables dt1 and dt2 in to new table dtnew ,but the result is weird .If first datatable has 3 rows and second one has 6 rows it is giving 18 rows result rather giving only matching rows values that means here 3 rows containing both table values.In Nutshell i created a third table `dtnew` and  designed structure ,then used condition .Anything wrong in the logic or is there any better way

```
DataSet ds = Exceltotable(@name);
                        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables.Count; i++)
                        {
                            if (ds.Tables[i].TableName == "Table2")
                            {
                                dt1 = ds.Tables[i];
                            }
                            if (ds.Tables[i].TableName == "Table3")
                            {
                                dt2 = ds.Tables[i];
                            }
                            if (dt1 != null && dt2 != null)
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        System.Data.DataTable dtnew = new System.Data.DataTable();
                        dtnew.Columns.Add("LOCATION", typeof(string));
                        dtnew.Columns.Add("RBSSHARE", typeof(string));
                        dtnew.Columns.Add("VENDOR", typeof(string));
                        dtnew.Columns.Add("PWRTYPE", typeof(string));
                        dtnew.Columns.Add("EQPTINSTYPE", typeof(string));
                        dtnew.Columns.Add("BTSHEIGHT", typeof(string));
                        dtnew.Columns.Add("BTSFAN", typeof(string));
                        dtnew.Columns.Add("HMSAVAIL", typeof(string));
                        dtnew.Columns.Add("MODELNAME", typeof(string));
                        dtnew.Columns.Add("MODELNO", typeof(string));
                        dtnew.Columns.Add("SERIALNO", typeof(string));
                        dtnew.Columns.Add("REVNO", typeof(string));
                        dtnew.Columns.Add("TECHNOLOGY", typeof(string));
                        dtnew.Columns.Add("Asset description", typeof(string));
                        dtnew.Columns.Add("Asset Category", typeof(string));
                        dtnew.Columns.Add("ASSETTAG", typeof(string));
                        dtnew.Columns.Add("ADDREMARK", typeof(string));
                        dtnew.Columns.Add("DELIVERYDATE", typeof(string));

                        var query = from  pp in dt1.AsEnumerable() 
                                    join ii in dt2.AsEnumerable()
                                        on pp.Field<string>("LOCATION") equals
                                            ii.Field<string>("LOCATION")

                                    select dtnew.LoadDataRow(new object[]
{
pp.Field<string>("LOCATION"),
pp.Field<string>("RBSSHARE"),
pp.Field<string>("VENDOR"),
pp.Field<string>("PWRTYPE"),
pp.Field<string>("EQPTINSTYPE"),
pp.Field<string>("BTSHEIGHT"),
pp.Field<string>("BTSFAN"),
pp.Field<string>("HMSAVAIL"),
pp.Field<string>("MODELNAME"),
pp.Field<string>("MODELNO"),
pp.Field<string>("SERIALNO"),
pp.Field<string>("REVNO"),
ii.Field<string>("TECHNOLOGY"),
ii.Field<string>("TECHNOLOGY"),
ii.Field<string>("Asset description"),
ii.Field<string>("ASSETTAG"),
ii.Field<string>("ADDREMARK"),
ii.Field<string>("DELIVERYDATE")
}, false);

                        query.CopyToDataTable();
                        ds.Tables.Add(dtnew);
```

Comment: This only works as expected if `LOCATION` is unique in each datatable.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
var query = 
    from row1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
    from row2 in dt2.AsEnumerable()
                   .Where(x => x["LOCATION"] == row1["LOCATION"])
                   .DefaultIfEmpty()
    select dtNew.LoadDataRow(new object[]
    {
        row1.Field<string>("LOCATION"),
        row1.Field<string>("RBSSHARE"),
        row1.Field<string>("VENDOR"),
        row1.Field<string>("PWRTYPE"),
        row1.Field<string>("EQPTINSTYPE"),
        row1.Field<string>("BTSHEIGHT"),
        row1.Field<string>("BTSFAN"),
        row1.Field<string>("HMSAVAIL"),
        row1.Field<string>("MODELNAME"),
        row1.Field<string>("MODELNO"),
        row1.Field<string>("SERIALNO"),
        row1.Field<string>("REVNO"),
        row2 == null ? null : row2.Field<string>("TECHNOLOGY"),
        row2 == null ? null : row2.Field<string>("TECHNOLOGY"),
        row2 == null ? null : row2.Field<string>("Asset description"),
        row2 == null ? null : row2.Field<string>("ASSETTAG"),
        row2 == null ? null : row2.Field<string>("ADDREMARK"),
        row2 == null ? null : row2.Field<string>("DELIVERYDATE")
    }, false);
```

Comment: I dont know what is going wrong ,it seems logic is correct but really dont know what went wrong.It is generating cartisian product

Comment: again giving 18 rows  - this is because the field LOCATION is not unique. You should join tables by unique field. DefaultIfEmpty() - it is left join, should work.

Comment: data is generated from excel file which is copied in to datatable.So if we can forget about the uniqueness of Location, do we have any other mechanism to pull all values from left table and matching values from second table

Comment: If many elements from the first table is associated with many of the elements in the second table then you should add a third table TableOneInTableTwo with the structure {id, tableOneId, tableTwoId}

Comment: i added strucutre like that only na?

Comment: Pay attention to your data. If you say that 3 records of one first table and 6 from the second after join by "LOCATION" give 18 records, then it means that the "LOCATION" is the same for all of these records, this is strange.