# Merge two datatable to one based on column

Tags: c#, merge, datatable

this question has been asked but mine has a different approach [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30409504/how-to-combine-two-data-table-and-merge-in-to-new-datatables)

l have a datatable with the following data

```
 DataTable dtProduct = new DataTable();
            dtProduct.Columns.Add("productId");
            dtProduct.Columns.Add("name");

            DataRow dataRow = dtProduct.NewRow();
            dataRow["productId"] = 1;
            dataRow["name"] = "Burger";
            dtProduct.Rows.Add(dataRow);


            DataRow dataRow2 = dtProduct.NewRow();
            dataRow2["productId"] = 2;
            dataRow2["name"] = "Chicken";
            dtProduct.Rows.Add(dataRow2);

            DataTable dtSales = new DataTable();
            dtSales.Columns.Add("productId");
            dtSales.Columns.Add("saleId");
            dtSales.Columns.Add("month");
            dtSales.Columns.Add("quantity");

            DataRow dataSalesRow = dtSales.NewRow();
            dataSalesRow["productId"] = 1;
            dataSalesRow["saleId"] = "1";
            dataSalesRow["month"] = "Jan";
            dataSalesRow["quantity"] = 3433;
            dtSales.Rows.Add(dataSalesRow);


            DataRow drSales2 = dtSales.NewRow();
            drSales2["productId"] = 1;
            drSales2["saleId"] = "2";
            drSales2["month"] = "Feb"; 
            drSales2["quantity"] = 56; 
            dtSales.Rows.Add(drSales2);

            DataRow drSales3 = dtSales.NewRow();
            drSales3["productId"] = 1;
            drSales3["saleId"] = "3";
            drSales3["month"] = "Mar";
            drSales3["quantity"] = 34522;
            dtSales.Rows.Add(drSales3);


            DataRow drSales4 = dtSales.NewRow();
            drSales4["productId"] = 2;
            drSales4["saleId"] = "4";
            drSales4["month"] = "Feb";
            drSales4["quantity"] = 345;
            dtSales.Rows.Add(drSales4);
```

And another sample 2

```
 DataTable dtStudents = new DataTable();
            dtStudents.Columns.Add("studentId");
            dtStudents.Columns.Add("fullname");

            DataRow drStudentrow = dtStudents.NewRow();
            drStudentrow["studentId"] = 1;
            drStudentrow["fullname"] = "Bil";
            dtStudents.Rows.Add(drStudentrow);

            DataRow drStudentrow2 = dtStudents.NewRow();
            drStudentrow2["studentId"] = 2;
            drStudentrow2["fullname"] = "Paul";
            dtStudents.Rows.Add(drStudentrow2);


            DataTable dtStudentExam = new DataTable();
            dtStudentExam.Columns.Add("studentId");
            dtStudentExam.Columns.Add("subjectId");
            dtStudentExam.Columns.Add("mark");

            DataRow dataStudentExamRow = dtStudentExam.NewRow();
            dataStudentExamRow["studentId"] = 1;
            dataStudentExamRow["subjectId"] = "E123";
            dataStudentExamRow["mark"] = 34;
            dtStudentExam.Rows.Add(dataStudentExamRow);

            DataRow dataStudentExamRow2 = dtStudentExam.NewRow();
            dataStudentExamRow2["studentId"] = 2;
            dataStudentExamRow2["subjectId"] = "E123";
            dataStudentExamRow2["mark"] = 90;
            dtStudentExam.Rows.Add(dataStudentExamRow2);

            DataRow dataStudentExamRow3 = dtStudentExam.NewRow();
            dataStudentExamRow3["studentId"] = 1;
            dataStudentExamRow3["subjectId"] = "E155";
            dataStudentExamRow3["mark"] = 78;
            dtStudentExam.Rows.Add(dataStudentExamRow3);

            DataRow dataStudentExamRow4 = dtStudentExam.NewRow();
            dataStudentExamRow4["studentId"] = 1;
            dataStudentExamRow4["subjectId"] = "E101";
            dataStudentExamRow4["mark"] = 12;
            dtStudentExam.Rows.Add(dataStudentExamRow4);

            DataRow dataStudentExamRow5 = dtStudentExam.NewRow();
            dataStudentExamRow5["studentId"] = 1;
            dataStudentExamRow5["subjectId"] = "E234";
            dataStudentExamRow5["mark"] = 42;
            dtStudentExam.Rows.Add(dataStudentExamRow5);
```

DataTable products(**dtProduct** ) has a productId which is the key and another data table sales (**dtSales**) has sales for the product based on month . and has a column productId .

what l want to achieve is merge this two tables to this 
[image]

Same Applies for students

l have a data table student (**dtStudents**) but l however l have student exam marks data tables (**dtStudentExam**) for each subject

and combine to something like this 
[image]

So my question is can l do this dynamically . l tried the following below

```
public static System.Data.DataTable MergeRowsToColumns(DataTable rowDataTable, string rowDataTableIdColumnName, string friendlyName, DataTable columData)
        {
            List<string> columnsToAdd = new List<string>();
            if (rowDataTable == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            DataTable finalDataTable = new DataTable();
            finalDataTable.Columns.Add(friendlyName.ToLower());
            finalDataTable.Columns.Add(rowDataTableIdColumnName.ToLower());

            foreach (DataColumn column in columData.Columns)
            {
                if (column.ColumnName.ToString() == rowDataTableIdColumnName.ToString())
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    finalDataTable.Columns.Add(column.ColumnName.ToString());
                    columnsToAdd.Add(column.ColumnName.ToString());
                }
            }

            foreach (DataRow row in rowDataTable.Rows)
            {
                DataRow newRow = finalDataTable.NewRow();
                newRow[rowDataTableIdColumnName] = row[rowDataTableIdColumnName];
                newRow[friendlyName] = row[friendlyName];
                foreach (DataRow columnRows in columData.Rows)
                {

                    foreach (string column in columnsToAdd)
                    {
                        var value = columnRows[column].ToString();
                        newRow[column] = value; 
                    }
                }
                finalDataTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
            }
            return finalDataTable;
        }
```

Algorithm logic 
Table 1 holds the key information 
Table 2 holds the value data for table

using a column name from **table one** for id which will be the same on **table 2**

can l do it generically 
in one function like

```
var dtMergedProducts = HelperDataTable.MergeRowsToColumns(dtProduct, "productId", "name", dtSales);
        var dtStudents = HelperDataTable.MergeRowsToColumns(dtStudents, "studentId", "fullname", dtStudentExam);
```

Please am retrieving the data as is hence can not group by in table 2 and also table two does not have a friendly name that will be displayed.

Most of the data that is loaded is not more than 100 000

this is the link of the helper utility am making [git hub](https://github.com/billywatsy/Avo/blob/master/Avo/Avo/HelperDataTable.cs)

**Edit One**

**DataTable 2**  will have  column value one for column and the other for value 
For example 
*dtSales*

1- month  : shown vertically

2- quantity: will be cell value

**Sample 2**

**dtStudentExam**

1- subjectId : shown vertically

2- mark      : will be the student mark

Comment: You have to create a new third datatable with all the columns defined.  Then you should be able to join the two tables and add results to new datatable.

Comment: @jdweng l got it working in the morning now ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

l got it working this morning

here if the method

```
public static System.Data.DataTable MergeRowsToColumns(DataTable rowDataTable, string rowDataTableIdColumnName, string friendlyName, DataTable dataAllValue , string dataColumnValue , string  dataColumnKey)
        {
            List<string> columnsToAdd = new List<string>();
            if (rowDataTable == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            DataTable finalDataTable = new DataTable();
            finalDataTable.Columns.Add(friendlyName.ToLower());
            finalDataTable.Columns.Add(rowDataTableIdColumnName.ToLower());

            foreach (DataRow row in dataAllValue.Rows)
            {
                if (row[rowDataTableIdColumnName].ToString() == rowDataTableIdColumnName.ToString())
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    var isExistColumnValue = columnsToAdd.Where(c => c == row[dataColumnKey].ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
                    if(isExistColumnValue == null)
                    {
                        columnsToAdd.Add(row[dataColumnKey].ToString());
                        finalDataTable.Columns.Add(row[dataColumnKey].ToString());
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach (DataRow row in rowDataTable.Rows)
            {
                DataRow newRow = finalDataTable.NewRow();
                newRow[rowDataTableIdColumnName] = row[rowDataTableIdColumnName];
                newRow[friendlyName] = row[friendlyName];
                foreach (DataRow columnRows in dataAllValue.Rows)
                { 
                    if(row[rowDataTableIdColumnName].ToString() != columnRows[rowDataTableIdColumnName].ToString())
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    var columnName = columnRows[dataColumnKey].ToString();
                    var columnValue = columnRows[dataColumnValue].ToString();
                    newRow[columnName] = columnValue; 
                }
                finalDataTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
            }
            return finalDataTable;
        }
```

it looked like l was failing on adding the column names before merging

you can just call like

```
var dt = HelperDataTable.MergeRowsToColumns(dtProduct, "productId", "name", dtSales , "quantity", "month");
           var dt2 = HelperDataTable.MergeRowsToColumns(dtStudents, "studentId", "fullname", dtStudentExam , "mark", "subjectId");
```